# Issue with merge sort Algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, merge, indexoutofboundsexception, mergesort

MergeSorting algorithm not working. Keep getting an `IndexOutOFBoundsError`. I believe the issue may be because there isn't a sentinel. I need to create a loop when the `leftarray` and `rightarray` is copying itself to `k`, one of the arrays runs out of numbers, which causes an error. I need some assistance creating this sentinel.

```java
private static <T> void mergeSort(Comparable<? extends T>[] items, int begIndx, int endIndx) {
    if (items.length > 1) {
        int midIndx = items.length / 2;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] left = (T[]) new Object[midIndx];
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] right = (T[]) new Object[items.length - midIndx];

        for (int i = 0; i < midIndx; i++) {
            left[i] = (T) items[i];
        }
        for (int i = midIndx; i < items.length; i++) {
            right[i] = (T) items[i];
        }

        mergeSort(items, begIndx, midIndx);
        mergeSort(items, midIndx + 1, endIndx);
        merge(items, begIndx, midIndx, endIndx);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> void merge(Comparable<? extends T>[] array,
                              int begIndx, int midIndx, int endIndx) {
    int sizeOfLeft = midIndx - begIndx + 1;
    int sizeOfRight = endIndx - midIndx;

    /// change to generic later
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] leftArr = (T[]) new Object[sizeOfLeft + 1];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] rightArr = (T[]) new Object[sizeOfRight + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfLeft; i++) {
        leftArr[i] = (T) array[begIndx + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfRight; j++) {
        rightArr[j] = (T) array[midIndx + j + 1];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    // changed to less than or equal to rather than "less than"
    // this is because this is a zero based index system
    // and because endeIndex is not a length but an index,
    // you need to populate it.
    for (int k = begIndx; k <= endIndx; k++) {
        // use comparable here
        if (((Integer) leftArr[i]).compareTo((Integer) rightArr[j]) <= 0) {
            array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>) leftArr[i];
            i = i + 1;
        } else if (((Integer) leftArr[i]).compareTo((Integer) rightArr[j]) >= 0) {
            /// just replaces it so don't use comparable
            array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>) rightArr[j];
            j = j + 1;
        } else if ((Integer) leftArr[sizeOfLeft] == null) {
            array[k] =  (Comparable<? extends T>) rightArr[j];
            j = j + 1;
        } else if ((Integer) rightArr[sizeOfRight] == null) {
            array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>) leftArr[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I created an integer array `arr = new Integer[5`]. So those 5 numbers should be sorted.

Comment: Please define "not working". Do you get an error? Not correct output?

Comment: I get an IndexoutOfbounds error.

Comment: At least one of your problems is that - in the first method - you access the right array with the range [midRange, items.length] while your right array has an index [0, items.length - midRange].

Comment: Your loop for the right array is wrongly defined. You're trying to assign to index `right[midIndx]` to begin with while you should be assigning to `right[i - midIndx]` but this is unfortunately not the only problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- it is unclear if the index `endIndx` is included or excluded. The code is much simpler if the `endIndx` is excluded, and the initial call to sort the array is simply: `mergesort(arr, 0, arr.length);`
- the initial test in `mergesort` is incorrect: instead of testing the array length, you should test if the slice has more than 1 element:

  ```
  if (endIndx - begIndx > 1)
  ```
- the arrays `left` and `right` are unused in `mergesort`.
- allocating an extra element in the arrays `left` and `right` in `merge` is not required, it is much simpler to compare the array index values against the lengths of the subarrays. This *sentinel* approach is confusing and should not be used.

Here is a simplified version:

```java
private static <T> void mergeSort(Comparable<? extends T>[] items, int begIndx, int endIndx) {
    if (endIndx - begIndx > 1) {
        int midIndx = items.length / 2;
        mergeSort(items, begIndx, midIndx);
        mergeSort(items, midIndx, endIndx);
        merge(items, begIndx, midIndx, endIndx);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> void merge(Comparable<? extends T>[] array,
                              int begIndx, int midIndx, int endIndx) {
    int sizeOfLeft = midIndx - begIndx;
    int sizeOfRight = endIndx - midIndx;

    /// change to generic later
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] leftArr = (T[]) new Object[sizeOfLeft];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] rightArr = (T[]) new Object[sizeOfRight];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfLeft; i++) {
        leftArr[i] = (T)array[begIndx + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfRight; j++) {
        rightArr[j] = (T)array[midIndx + j];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = begIndx;

    while (i < sizeOfLeft && j < sizeOfRight) {
        /// use comparable to compare actual values
        if ((Integer)leftArr[i]).compareTo((Integer)rightArr[j]) <= 0) {
            array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>)leftArr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>)rightArr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i < sizeOfLeft) {
        array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>)leftArr[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < sizeOfRight) {
        array[k] = (Comparable<? extends T>)rightArr[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```